# Swapping nested dependency when requesting a specific object in StructureMap 3

Tags: structuremap, structuremap3

I am trying to swap a nested dependency when resolving a specific instance using StructureMap. In 2.x I was able to do this with the following `UseSpecial` code, but it does not work in 3.x

The code is basically saying... when requesting an instance of `IObject`, swap the default instance for `ITwo` with `AnotherTwo` which is a dependency of `IObject`'s dependency.

```
public class MyStructureMapRegistry : Registry
{
    public MyStructureMapRegistry()
    {
        For<IObject>().UseSpecial(cfg => cfg.ConstructedBy(x =>
        {
            x.RegisterDefault(typeof(ITwo), x.GetInstance<AnotherTwo>());
            return x.GetInstance<DependsOnOne>();
        }));
    }
}
```

The following is the sample object graph that I am trying to wire up.

```
public interface IObject { }
public interface IOne { }
public interface ITwo { }

public class DependsOnOne : IObject
{
    IOne _one;

    public DependsOnOne(IOne one)
    {
        _one = one;
    }
}

public class DependsOnTwo : IOne
{
    ITwo _two;

    public DependsOnTwo(ITwo two)
    {
        _two = two;
    }
}

public class Two : ITwo { }
public class AnotherTwo : ITwo { }
```